# HashMap initialization NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

The console is pointing to a null pointer exception on the "variable" line:

```
variable = spritePanel.getVariables();
    for(String s: variable.keySet()){
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append(variable.get(s));
        sb.append("<br>");          
    }
```

At the top of my code, I have:

```
public HashMap<String,Double> variable = new HashMap<String,Double>();
```

The spritePanel is an instance of another class that is in the same package, the method getVariables() returns a HashMap.

Advanced thanks for the help.

Edit - 
So here's the whole method:

```
private String formatVariables() {

    spritePosition = spritePanel.getSpritePosition(0);
    double xcoor = spritePosition.getX();
    double ycoor = spritePosition.getY();
    double direc = spritePosition.getDirection();
    boolean pendown = spritePosition.getIsPenDown();
    boolean visibility = spritePosition.getIsHiding();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("<html><p align=left>");
    sb.append("X = ");
    sb.append(xcoor);
    sb.append("<br>");
    sb.append("Y = ");
    sb.append(ycoor);
    sb.append("<br>");
    sb.append("Direction = ");
    sb.append(direc);
    sb.append("<br>");
    sb.append("PenDown = ");
    sb.append(pendown);
    sb.append("<br>");
    sb.append("Sprite Hidden = ");
    sb.append(visibility);
    sb.append("<br>");

            //sb.append("</p></html>");
            //before I added the variable HashMap, the string buffer code worked


    variable = spritePanel.getVariables();  //this is where it breaks according to the console
    for(String s: variable.keySet()){
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append(variable.get(s));
        sb.append("<br>");          
    }

    sb.append("</p></html>");
    return sb.toString();       
}
```

Comment: It looks like `spritePanel` is `null`. We need to see more code if you want more substantive help.

Comment: Your method `spritePanel.getVariables()` returns `null`. It doesn't matter that you have initialized `variable` with a HashMap on top of your code because you overwrite it later with `spritePanel.getVariables()`

Comment: With "variable" line, do you mean the first or the second line of your code? (since they both refer to `variable`)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt if spritePanel.getVariables() returns null, it wont show NullpointerException it's may be because spritePanel itself will be null in line 1 but there might be possible at line 4.

Comment: @VishalSantharam if `spritePanel.getVariables()` returns null then you will get a NullPointerException on the second line.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco, I added the whole method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just means that spritePanel is null when `variable = spritePanel.getVariables();` gets executed. Java throws that exception when a variable is set to null and you tried to call a method with that variable. To visualize, that line will be executed like this: `variable = null.getVariables();` in which null has no method called getVariables(). Try investigating when did spritePanel become null.